# Taglist isn't reading custom Markdown tags

Tags: tags, ctags, plugin-taglist

The plugin Taglist is showing tags perfectly for my python but not for my markdown files.

There is a MCVE [on github](https://github.com/joereddington/MCVE4SE).

I have two files. test1.py is:

```
def one():
    print("one")

def two():
    print("two")
```

and test2.md is:

```
# One

The Quick brown fox

# Two

Jumped over the lazy dog
```

I use the following .ctags file:

```
--langdef=markdown
--langmap=markdown:.md
--regex-markdown=/^#[ \t](.*$)/\1/f,heading,headings/
```

The command

```
ctags test1.py test2.md
```

creates a tag file, with all four tags in:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8     //
One     test2.md        /^# One $/;"    f
Two     test2.md        /^# Two$/;"     f
one     test1.py        /^def one(): $/;"       f
two     test1.py        /^def two(): $/;"       f
```

but when I open the editor. I have:

[image]

why are my markdown tags not showing?

Comment: This may be better asked of the plugin maintainers

Comment: I'm open to feedback on the question - I thought I did everything right and still got downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can't answer definitively. Questions about configuring plugins correctly are a tough nut for this community: some people don't mind, and some people seem really against them. (I've not seen anyone _love_ them.) All in all, I thought the Q was pretty well put together, so have a neutralizing upvote. Next time, maybe poke around in the plugin's documentation or community, too (https://github.com/yegappan/taglist/blob/master/doc/taglist.txt#L1204). And a link to the correct plugin is helpful.

Comment: all useful. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the following line to your .vimrc file:

let tlist_markdown_settings = 'markdown;f:Heading'

Another approach is to use Universal Ctags (https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) instead of exuberant ctags. Universal Ctags natively supports tags for markdown files.